How can I increase the precision of a Yolov8n model for detecting phones and books in cluttered images?
I recently trained a yolov8n model on my dataset to detect phones and books for exam proctoring. I have trained it on 35k images consisting of phones, books, and people holding books and phones. My problem is that sometimes the background is getting detected as a phone or a book and at some angles a phone is getting detected as book. The dataset is a summation of images that I downloaded from Roboflow and a subset of COCO that depicts books and phones. How can I increase performance?

There are many ways to increase performance. You can add augmentations to your images, you could increase the amount of data you are using and the variation of that data. Depending on your hardware and the complexity of your data, it might even make sense to use a larger YOLO model.
